# Can I have adobe AIR work with mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, air, cloud, adobe, couchbase

Adobe Air uses sql-Lite, a relational database, can I make it use mongoDB instead for a cloud based educational game that is played via an app?

Also, for another app I also wanted to create a redundant cloud set up with replication across 3 different geographical regions. Can I do this with Air or better served with another noSQL choice?

(my concerns are the Air/SQL combo may not be fast enough for large scale access on the cloud for gaming, and synched replication across sites may not be possible or as simple as mongoDB or Couchbase)